# Using and further parsing of form.errors.as_json to return http response in Django

Tags: json, ajax, django

I am relatively new to both JSON and Django forms. And I wonder how Djagno's `user_form.errors.as_json()` should be used to transfer error messages to client-slde. Right now, I have the following code:

On the server-side. I have:

```
if form.is_valid():
    # some code
else:
    return JsonResponse(user_form.errors.as_json(), status = 400, safe = False)
```

Client:

```
$.post('/url/', data, function(response){
        // Success   
    }).fail(function(response){ 
        var errors = $.parseJSON($.parseJSON(response.responseText)); // looks stupid
```

The akward line `$.parseJSON($.parseJSON(response.responseText));` proves that I am doing something wrong. Can anyone provide a best-practice code pattern for sending and parsing jsonified form errors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are You are converting to JSON twice - once when you call `as_json`, then again when you use `JsonResponse`.

You could use `HttpResponse` with `form.errors.as_json()`:

```
return HttpResponse(user_form.errors.as_json(), status = 400, content_type='application/json')
```

Note the warnings in the [`as_json`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json) docs about escaping results to avoid a cross site scripting attack. You should ensure the results are escaped if you use `JsonResponse` as well.

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`. If I remove `'application/json'`, it's ok. Did you misprint something ?)

Comment: It should be `content_type='application/json'`

Comment: Great! A bit off-topic, do you think it's ok to return 400 status for invalid form? Or I should return 200 or 500 instead ?

Comment: I agree that's off topic. You definitely shouldn't return `500` - there is no server error. Returning `400` makes it easy to distinguish between valid and invalid forms, and allows you to use `.fail()` in your JavaScript.

Comment: The 2 'alternatives' actually give different results.  For example, the latter doesn't include the error codes.

Comment: @TimTisdall good point, `form.errors` does not contain the error codes. I have removed that section from the answer. If you want to access the error codes in Python, there is an [`as_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_data) method.